# Sounds nice/fine is the same as saying sounds good/great?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

I'm in doubt if **'sounds nice/fine'** it has the same meaning: 'used for telling someone that their idea or suggestion seems like a good one.'

I know **'sounds good/great'** it has.

*Examples:*

That **sounds nice**, really nice.
**Sounds fine**, but I'm not looking for a job.

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion. Sure - almost everyone would agree that *with no other context*, "great" is far stronger than "nice", for example. But *in practice*, attempting to "grade" adjectives like this is a bit of a mug's game. Some people in some contexts would use "fine" to convey *extreme* approval *(Rover was certainly a **fine** dog)*, whereas other people in other contexts might use it to simply signify reluctant agreement *(**Fine** - we'll do it your way, if you insist)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good** and **great** are much stronger adjectives than **nice** and **fine**, but all four are OK to use. However, you should be aware that sometimes, **nice** and **fine** are used when the person really means the opposite.

For example, in the United States today, especially when chatting in social media, people will use **nice** when they don't like something, but they don't want to say something negative or hurt your feelings. For example, if they don't like your picture, they might say it's **nice** when they really mean it's ugly.

**Fine** can be used to capitulate and move on from something that you don't really agree with. For example, if we're arguing over whether to pick the green item or the blue item, I might say "Pick the blue, that's fine" when I really want the green one because otherwise we would be arguing about it all day and never make any progress.

They aren't always used this way. They might be used normally. However, it's helpful to be aware of hidden meanings, and those meanings aren't there for **good** and **great**, only for **nice** and **fine**.

Comment: Used car dealer: This Cadillac is priced at $1200. Me: Fine. I'll take it. No sarcasm or reluctance.

Comment: Thank you very much!